# CMake linker cannot find library that does not begin with "lib"

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using CMake to compile an application which uses the [HSImage](https://github.com/DTChuck/HSImage) library on github. After installing with pip, the HSI library generates a shared library file, in my case it is created at `/usr/src/HSI/HSI.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so`

I am trying to link this library to my application with CMake, but the CMake `find_library` method is having some trouble finding the library. Here is the relevant part of my CMakeLists.txt file:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(HSI_DIR /usr/src/HSI)
find_library(HSI_LIB HSI.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu PATHS ${HSI_DIR})
message(STATUS "HSI:  ${HSI_LIB}")  # outputs /usr/src/HSI/HSI.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} <sources...>)
target_link_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ${HSI_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME}
        ${HSI_LIB}
        <other libs...>
        -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs
    )
```

When building, this produces the following error message:

```
cd /home/nvidia/projects/HsiInference/build;/usr/local/bin/cmake --build "/home/nvidia/projects/HsiInference/build" --target hsi_inference_onnx  --  ;

Scanning dependencies of target hsi_inference_onnx
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/targets/HsiInferenceOnnx/main_onnx.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/targets/HsiInferenceOnnx/HsiInferenceOnnx.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/src/ftpnano.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/src/getOptions.cpp.o
[ 71%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/src/logger.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/src/utils.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable hsi_inference_onnx_debug
CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/build.make:245: recipe for target 'hsi_inference_onnx_debug' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:123: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/all' failed
**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSI.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu**
**collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
make[3]: *** [hsi_inference_onnx_debug] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:130: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hsi_inference_onnx.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:196: recipe for target 'hsi_inference_onnx' failed
make: *** [hsi_inference_onnx] Error 2

Build failed.
```

The important part:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSI.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From what I have gathered, `target_link_libraries` simply adds `-l<library_name>` to the link command, and `-l<library_name>` assumes that there is a file called `lib<library_name>.so` to link, which is not the case here. **How can I get CMake to link the library properly despite the weird filename?**

NOTE:
I am able to get the project to build by doing the following:

- Delete the project's `build` directory to clear CMake caches
- Rename the file or create a symbolic link to `libhsi.so`
- Change CMakeLists.txt to `find_library(HSI_LIB hsi PATHS ${HSI_DIR})`

This changes the link command to `-lhsi` instead, which is able to find the renamed/soft-linked library file. HOWEVER, this is not ideal for me and the original question remains unanswered :)

Comment: You can provide a full path in the `target_link_library` and CMake will not add the `-l` option to it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried hardcoding the full library path into the arguments of `target_link_library` and it produces the same error, even after deleting the `build` directory :/

Comment: Why do you use `target_link_directories`? This command is needed only when you have only a name of the library. But `find_library` gives you an absolute path.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are correct, it is not necessary in this case. I think it's leftover from when I had a different command that linked the library by filename only. Either way the absolute path doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect you link both by full path and by name somehow (or have a broken CMake version, that happens too).

Comment: Do a verbose build and look at the actual commands and their options. I also suspect the same thing as @numzero, and it will be very visible if you can see the actual commands used for building.

Answer (score 3):

For libraries with weird filename you should add `:` before the filename. Be careful, like mentioned in https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld :  If namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path for a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path for a file called libnamespec.a (namespec is what comes after -l).

For your example you should replace  `${HSI_LIB}` in target_link_libraries by  `:${HSI_LIB}.so`.